# What is the meaning of the blue lettering on the board from Cabin in the Woods?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-cabin-in-the-woods

On the board of all the monsters in [The Cabin in the Woods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cabin_in_the_Woods) what does the blue lettering mean written next to the Monster's name?

[image: The board]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Blue letters represent the group which bid on the monster. Do you remember the scene at the start of the movie where they start collecting money from the people working ? That's what the money is for.

For example in the movie The Redneck Torture family was chosen by the characters. The Maintenance team bet on that before the group spends their night at the cabin. Oh I forgot the intern chips in too on that same bet as well.